# Parsing json into an array to show plain text in NSLog

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

I have downloaded some json data from a json call now Iam trying to parse the following json into an array so that I can see a list of the questions in my NSlog?

e.g

```
NSLog(@"Questions:Air cleaner (Primary), Air Cleaner (Secondary));  

[
{"SurveyAnswerTypeID":4,"Question":"Air cleaner (Primary)"},

{"SurveyAnswerTypeID":4,"Question":"Air Cleaner (Secondary)"}
]
```

I am trying to put this into an array and it will only return one array e.g Air cleaner (Primary)

```
  NSString *searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ddproam.co.za/Central/Survey/GetSurveyQuestions?surveyId=%@",self.surveyQuestionIDParsed];

searchQuery = [searchQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchQuery]];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:searchQuery];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"strResult: %@",strResult);

NSLog(@"searchQuery: %@", searchQuery);

NSError *error;

self.json2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL 
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&error];

NSDictionary* defineJsonData = [self.json2 lastObject]; 

NSNumber* surveyID = [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"SurveyID"];
NSLog(@"UserID: %@", surveyID);

NSArray* userQuestions = [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"Question"];

NSLog(@"Question for Survey: %@", userQuestions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine. Two observations:

1. When you set `defineJsonData` you're only grabbing the last item. If you want to iterate through all of them, you'd do something like:

   ```
   for (NSDictionary *defineJsonData in self.json2)
   {
       NSNumber* surveyID = [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"SurveyID"];
       NSLog(@"SurveyID: %@", surveyID);

       NSArray* userQuestions = [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"Question"]; //for actual json response
       NSLog(@"Question for Survey: %@", userQuestions); //3
   }
   ```
2. As an aside, your two lines that create the `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest` objects are obviously not needed as the data has already been loaded and you don't use these two objects.

Comment: Thanks so much for making me understand better. This makes a lot of sense. Thank You. @Rob